# Select in QTableView from QAbstractTableModel item

Tags: qt, tableview, selection

I created `TableView` (by inhereting from `QTableView`) and `Model` (by inhereting from `QAbstractTableModel`) and implemented all their functions that I needed, but now I have to add strange feature - those objects (stored in models) have to be able to cause table view to select "their" row.

It comes from the fact that there is always graphic object related to them and whenever I click on a scene on a certain object, I wish to center on its representation in table view. Can I do this?

Comment: You could focus on the line by emulate a click or double-click on it. Perhaps it could work ?

Comment: But how? I just have pointer to table item (single item contained in model and that mdoel is used by the view as source) - how do i get from here to there?

Comment: Oh, yes, I read QTableWidget instead of QTableView. I never used QTableView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You model could implement a signal emitted every time you want to change the selection. Something like this:

```
void CMyModel::sigUpdateSelection(const QItemSelection & selection, QItemSelectionModel::SelectionFlags flags);
```

And than you could connect this signal to the QItemSelectionModel of your table view. This is how you get the selection model:

```
QTableView* view = new QTableView(parent);
QItemSelectionModel* selectionModel = view->selectionModel();
```

`QItemSelectionModel` has a slot `select()`. This is where you will connect your signal.

And this is how you will emit:

```
// Add to current selection
emit sigUpdateSelection(QItemSelection(indexLeft, indexRight), QItemSelectionModel::Select);

// Clear current selection and select new one
emit sigUpdateSelection(QItemSelection(indexLeft, indexRight), QItemSelectionModel::ClearAndSelect);
```